# Blackberry BBM : connecting MDS to simulator

Tags: blackberry

I am unable to get my simulators to talk to the BBM MDS. I have followed all the instructions in the BBM getting started giude.Since i am behind a proxy , i have also added the proxy comfiguration to the rimconfig file in the MDS1 folder of BBM.After i execute run.bat of the BBM MDS,i get the following output in the MDS window.

```
SCM 3.5.3.30 30 20110614
    <2011-12-27 10:21:07.563 IST>:[0]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, Admin. Task- H
    TTP Proxy Mappings>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:07.706 IST>:[1]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, Admin. Task- r
    efresh media management>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:08.127 IST>:[2]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, The push servi
    ce is ready to receive requests>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.618 IST>:[3]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = J2SE 1
    .6.0_22 Charsets supported:Big5,Big5-HKSCS,EUC-JP,EUC-KR,GB18030,GB2312,GBK,IBM-
    Thai,IBM00858,IBM01140,IBM01141,IBM01142,IBM01143,IBM01144,IBM01145,IBM01146,IBM
    01147,IBM01148,IBM01149,IBM037,IBM1026,IBM1047,IBM273,IBM277,IBM278,IBM280,IBM28
    4,IBM285,IBM297,IBM420,IBM424,IBM437,IBM500,IBM775,IBM850,IBM852,IBM855,IBM857,I
    BM860,IBM861,IBM862,IBM863,IBM864,IBM865,IBM866,IBM868,IBM869,IBM870,IBM871,IBM9
    18,ISO-2022-CN,ISO-2022-JP,ISO-2022-JP-2,ISO-2022-KR,ISO-8859-1,ISO-8859-13,ISO-
    8859-15,ISO-8859-2,ISO-8859-3,ISO-8859-4,ISO-8859-5,ISO-8859-6,ISO-8859-7,ISO-88
    59-8,ISO-8859-9,JIS_X0201,JIS_X0212-1990,KOI8-R,KOI8-U,Shift_JIS,TIS-620,US-ASCI
    I,UTF-16,UTF-16BE,UTF-16LE,UTF-32,UTF-32BE,UTF-32LE,UTF-8,windows-1250,windows-1
    251,windows-1252,windows-1253,windows-1254,windows-1255,windows-1256,windows-125
    7,windows-1258,windows-31j,x-Big5-Solaris,x-euc-jp-linux,x-EUC-TW,x-eucJP-Open,x
    -IBM1006,x-IBM1025,x-IBM1046,x-IBM1097,x-IBM1098,x-IBM1112,x-IBM1122,x-IBM1123,x
    -IBM1124,x-IBM1381,x-IBM1383,x-IBM33722,x-IBM737,x-IBM834,x-IBM856,x-IBM874,x-IB
    M875,x-IBM921,x-IBM922,x-IBM930,x-IBM933,x-IBM935,x-IBM937,x-IBM939,x-IBM942,x-I
    BM942C,x-IBM943,x-IBM943C,x-IBM948,x-IBM949,x-IBM949C,x-IBM950,x-IBM964,x-IBM970
    ,x-ISCII91,x-ISO-2022-CN-CNS,x-ISO-2022-CN-GB,x-iso-8859-11,x-JIS0208,x-JISAutoD
    etect,x-Johab,x-MacArabic,x-MacCentralEurope,x-MacCroatian,x-MacCyrillic,x-MacDi
    ngbat,x-MacGreek,x-MacHebrew,x-MacIceland,x-MacRoman,x-MacRomania,x-MacSymbol,x-
    MacThai,x-MacTurkish,x-MacUkraine,x-MS932_0213,x-MS950-HKSCS,x-mswin-936,x-PCK,x
    -SJIS_0213,x-UTF-16LE-BOM,X-UTF-32BE-BOM,X-UTF-32LE-BOM,x-windows-50220,x-window
    s-50221,x-windows-874,x-windows-949,x-windows-950,x-windows-iso2022jp>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.622 IST>:[4]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = SCM, DefaultJobPool
    Pool size = 10>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.622 IST>:[5]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = SCM, DefaultJobPool
    Queue length = 20>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.622 IST>:[6]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = SCM, maxMem: 518979
    584 maxPoolSize: 10>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.853 IST>:[7]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Connec
    ted, TOPSERVICE = KEYNEGO, LOWERSERVICE = GME>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.854 IST>:[8]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Connec
    ted, TOPSERVICE = SERVICE_BOOK, LOWERSERVICE = GME>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.854 IST>:[9]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Connec
    ted, TOPSERVICE = SRPH, LOWERSERVICE = GME>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.854 IST>:[10]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
    cted, TOPSERVICE = CMIME, LOWERSERVICE = GME>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.855 IST>:[11]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
    cted, TOPSERVICE = RIM_IM, LOWERSERVICE = GME>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.855 IST>:[12]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
    cted, TOPSERVICE = IPPP, LOWERSERVICE = GME>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.855 IST>:[13]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
    cted, TOPSERVICE = GME, LOWERSERVICE = MDP>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.856 IST>:[14]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
    cted, TOPSERVICE = REG, LOWERSERVICE = MDP>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.856 IST>:[15]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
    cted, TOPSERVICE = MDP, LOWERSERVICE = GPAK>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:09.856 IST>:[16]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
    cted, TOPSERVICE = GPAK, LOWERSERVICE = UDP>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.078 IST>:[17]:<BBM_MDS>:<EVENT>:<LAYER = SCM, BBM MDS_START
    MDS; >
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.085 IST>:[18]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SRPH, LAYER = SRPH
    , EVENT = Initialization>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.194 IST>:[19]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<maxMem: 518979584 maxQueue
    Size: 250>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.201 IST>:[20]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SRPH, LAYER = SRPH
    , EVENT = Started>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.205 IST>:[21]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SRPH, EVENT = Star
    ted, THREAD = SRPHprotocolMainThread>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.208 IST>:[22]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SRPH, EVENT = Star
    ted, THREAD = SRPHListenOnDatagramStatus>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.208 IST>:[23]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SRPH, EVENT = Star
    ted, THREAD = SRPHListenForClientsPackets>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.212 IST>:[24]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SRPH, EVENT = Star
    ted, THREAD = SRPHQueuesManager>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.321 IST>:[25]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SB, EVENT = Starte
    d, THREAD = ListenOnDatagramStatus>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.357 IST>:[26]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SB, EVENT = Starte
    d, THREAD = ListenForClientsStatus>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.358 IST>:[27]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, EVENT = Initi
    alization>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.516 IST>:[28]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = SCM, BBMSessionJob
    Pool Pool size = 10>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.519 IST>:[29]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = SCM, BBMSessionJob
    Pool Queue length = 20>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:10.522 IST>:[30]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = SCM, BBMSessionJob
    Pool Queue length = 1280>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:11.989 IST>:[31]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, EVENT = Start
    ed>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:11.992 IST>:[32]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, Try to create
    BBMPinFilter instance>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:11.992 IST>:[33]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, EVENT = Start
    ed, THREAD = BBM::ListenOnDatagramStatus>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:11.997 IST>:[34]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, EVENT = Start
    ed, THREAD = QueuesManager>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.060 IST>:[35]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, Start loading
    filteredPins>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.195 IST>:[36]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, 0 filtered pi
    ns have been loaded successfully>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.198 IST>:[37]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, Schedule relo
    ad filteredPins task with interval [86400s>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.249 IST>:[38]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = SCM, EP2PJobManage
    rDefaultJobPool Pool size = 10>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.301 IST>:[39]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = EP2P, Start loadin
    g the store file ep2p_store.dat. Size is 0 bytes [0.0 MB].>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.307 IST>:[40]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = EP2P, Removed 0 fr
    ee block(s) from ep2p_store.dat
    End loading the store file ep2p_store.dat. Size is 0 bytes [0.0 MB].>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.344 IST>:[41]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, Try to create
    BBMVersionFilter instance>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.395 IST>:[42]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, Start loading
    VersionsReleased>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.422 IST>:[43]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, 0 versions re
    leased have been loaded successfully>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.424 IST>:[44]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, Schedule relo
    ad versionReleased task with interval [86400s]>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.486 IST>:[45]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, Start loading
    plugin controls>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.556 IST>:[46]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, 0 platform ap
    p controls have been loaded successfully>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.559 IST>:[47]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, Schedule relo
    ad plugin controls task with interval [86400s]>
    Dec 27, 2011 10:21:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
    INFO: Starting tomcat server
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.782 IST>:[48]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, Admin. Task-
    HTTP Proxy Mappings>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:12.785 IST>:[49]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, Admin. Task-
    refresh media management>
    Dec 27, 2011 10:21:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.28
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.143 IST>:[50]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = KeyNego, Cannot in
    itialize AES-256: Did you install Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files?>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, net.rim.application.ipproxyservice.b.a: Initialize failed>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, at net.rim.application.ipproxyservice.IPProxyServiceApplication.start(Un
    known Source)>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, at net.rim.application.ipproxyservice.IPProxyServiceApplication.main(Unk
    nown Source)>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, at net.rim.protocol.keynego.a.c.Xg(Unknown Source)>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, at net.rim.protocol.keynego.a.c.<init>(Unknown Source)>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, at net.rim.protocol.keynego.KeyNegoProtocol.kE(Unknown Source)>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, at net.rim.protocol.keynego.KeyNegoProtocol.start(Unknown Source)>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, at net.rim.service.c.start(Unknown Source)>
    <2011-12-27 10:21:15.156 IST>:[51]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
    tion, ... 2 more>
    C:\BBM SDK v1.1 for BlackBerry Java\MDS Simulator\MDSv3.5.3\sdk\mds\Servers\MDS1
```

After this point , when i run the sim1.bat and sim2.bat and try to connect to the internet,i don see anything happening in the MDS window. In the simulator i get an error "Cannot find the requested server" .Has anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things....

1) BBM is incompatible with Java 7... If you are using tat, it wont work... See to it you use Blackberry 6 simulators also, i mean the 9800 and not the 9900...

2) BBM is incompatible with jre-64-bit.... Normally if you have automatic update installed on your Windows7, there are very high changes of you having the 64-bit version.... Go to control panel, remove the 64-bit... If still not working, then uninstall 32-bit also and reinstall only the 32-bit.

If the above mentioned things doesnt work for you, let me know.